# Is all communication between workers in Dask Distributed via the scheduler?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm trying to establish if all the workers in my cluster need to be able to see each other, or just the scheduler process. When data needs to be transferred between workers, do they communicate directly, or send data via the sheduler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workers should ideally be able to communicate directly with each other, to be able to quicker copy data (results) as needed. You do not want to make your scheduler the single bottleneck for *data* communication; all messages and tasks pass through the scheduler, but these tend to be much smaller.

EDIT: docs link: http://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/journey.html#step-5-execute-on-the-worker

Comment: Thanks. So the default is that the scheduler tells the workers about each other, and when data needs to be moved, they cut out the middle man? Can it fall back to man-in-the-middle if they cannot see each other?

Comment: Somewhat answering my own question: 
http://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/journey.html#step-5-execute-on-the-worker suggests that workers fetch data from other worker, having been told by the scheduler where it can be found.

Comment: I added the link, although I suspect there is a more concrete form of "what your cluster requires" somewhere.